# Jboss AS7 session timeout config

Tags: http, jboss7.x, session-timeout

I hope you can help me, 
I'm migrating from JBoss 5 to 7 and I need to configure the http session timeout because I have to mantain session during long uploads from client. 
Do you know how to do it? In JBoss 5 I configured it in deployers/jbossweb.deployer/web.xml. But seems to be different in AS7 version.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems you also asked this here: http://jboss-as7-development.1055759.n5.nabble.com/Jboss-AS-7-http-session-timeout-td5710122.html . When you ask the same question in multiple places it's nice to link between them so nobody repeats work and other people can find the answers better.

Answer (score 4):

The short version appears to be that in JBoss AS 7 you can't globally configure a session timeout, at least as of 7.1.1.Final and as far as I can find out.

Configure it in the `web.xml` of your individual deployments instead. For guidance on setting it in `web.xml`, see, eg, http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/how-to-configure-the-session-timeout-in-servlet/